# Zeros of the Bessel's function $J_0(z)$

Tags: complex-analysis, bessel-functions, entire-functions

I am particularly interested in finding a form for the zeros of the Bessel's function $J_0(z)$. I have read somewhere that it has infinite number of zeros (need reference for this). But, in order to study their properties, I need to know some form of them (if such a form exists). Can anyone help? I am also keen to go through the existing literature on this topic if any exists.

Comment: No closed form available.  There are reams of information on this topic; just google it or pick up an applied math book on special functions. For example, good asymptotic approximations available in Digital Library Mathematical Functions 10.21.